# Heroku application error h10 and web.1 crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I just uploaded my ruby on rails app to heroku and I keep getting an h10 error when I try to visit any pages.

Also when I run the command 'heroku ps' it tells me it crashed and gives me this output

```
=== web (1X): `bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV`
web.1: crashed 2014/10/06 17:51:39 (~ 18s ago)\
```

I followed the tutorial here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#local-workstation-setup

I tried running heroku logs but there really isn't anything helpful there all it says is status code 503 and code=H10

Is there a way to get a more accurate log so I can have a better idea of what is happening here?

Comment: What do `echo $PORT` and `echo $RAILS_ENV` output? What web server are you using?

Comment: I'm using heroku... this is just what it generated..

Comment: Have you tried starting it locally in production mode?

Comment: Are really sure that there's nothing else in the logs?

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! I found the issue by running in production mode locally and it was a really quick fix